# .torrent files downloaded using python urllib2 fail to open in bittorrent client

Tags: python, gzip, urllib2, bittorrent

I'm using this code to download .torrent files:

```
torrent = urllib2.urlopen(torrent URL, timeout = 30)
output = open('mytorrent.torrent', 'wb')
output.write(torrent.read())
```

The resultant mytorrent.torrent file doesn't open in any bittorrent client and throws up "unable to parse meta file" error. The problem apparently is that although the torrent URL (e.g. http://torcache.com/torrent-file-1.torrent) ends with a '.torrent' suffix, it is compressed using gzip and needs to be uncompressed and then saved as a torrent file. I've confirmed this by unzipping the file in terminal:`gunzip mytorrent.torrent > test.torrent` and opening the file in the bittorrent client which opens fine.

How do I modify python to look up the file encoding and figure out how the file is compressed and use the right tool to uncompress it and save as a .torrent file?

Answer (score 1):

gzip'ed data must be unziped. You can deteted this, if you look out for the content-encoding header.

```
import gzip, urllib2, StringIO

req = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
response = opener.open(req)
data = response.read()
if response.info()['content-encoding'] == 'gzip':
    gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(StringIO(fileobj=data))
    plain = gzipper.read()
    data = plain
output.write(data)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzip_torrent.py", line 16, in <module>
    plain = gzipper.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 249, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 283, in _read
    pos = self.fileobj.tell()   # Save current position
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'`